# Where are Sticky Notes stored (Windows 10)?

Tags: windows-10, sticky-notes

Up until Windows 8, they are apparently stored in `%AppData%\Microsoft\Sticky Notes`, but that location does not exist in Windows 10.

From where can I (programmatically) obtain the contents of sticky notes from?

Comment: Look here:  C:\Users\logon\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Sticky Notes and they should be there.

Comment: @John , not on my Windows 10 box.  I have given more specifics  below.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft keeps moving these around and obscuring the content.  That's their right I guess.. :)

Try:
`C:\Users\<your user name>\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.MicrosoftStickyNotes_8wekyb3d8bbwe\LocalState`

You will need a (free) viewer capable of reading a SQLite database file.  Any SQLite viewer should do.
You will need to poke around to figure out the format they are using (I am not going to do that for you) but I assure you that the data you seek is there.  I just poked around my own copy :) .. thanks!  .. I wouldn't have known where they moved this stuff if you hadn't asked.  BTW, I used the SystemInternals Process Monitor to figure out where the data was getting written.